# Firebase Activity opening on every device

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im making my first more complex app and can't think of any soultion. I use FirebaseAuth and signing in with google. I'm connecting to my app with my real device with one account, and on the emulator with another account. I have a simple voting system in my app, when you open a profile you can either give it a thumbs up or thumbs down and it uptades points in realtime database. The problem is, when I vote for a profile in one device, the same profile open's up on every device that is connected, no matter what was opened there.

This is what my console shows everytime i vote:

```
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
      Activity resumed, time: 3529424
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs),
Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=ViewRestaurantInfo, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-6386294285516809459, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ViewRestaurantInfo, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-6386294285516809458}]
```